# Run two figwheel servers in one jvm

Tags: node.js, jvm, clojurescript, figwheel

Is it possible to launch two figwheel servers via figwheel-sidecar from within one process/jmv?

In a development environment I'm trying to launch one figwheel server for communicating with a webbrowser. Another one should do so with a node.js application. I want to avoid having two jvm's running for this.

I could manage to run them one after another, the browser and the nodejs conneciton. But it seems, whenever another call to `start-figwheel`! is done, the other connection is being closed. To me it looks like figwheel is only done for having one server, is this true?